# Porting GNU sed command to BSD sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, freebsd

I’m porting a shell script written for Linux to FreeBSD, and have come across this line:

```
local from_conf="$(sed -rn "s/^$1=('|\"|)(.*)\1/\2/ip" "$CONF" | tail -n 1)"
```

It’s used as part of a function to get properties out of a configuration file ($CONF), so adding in actual variable values it may look something like:

```
local from_conf="$(sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=('|\"|)(.*)\1/\2/ip" "/etc/msm.conf" | tail -n 1)"
```

Under GNU sed (v4.2.2 in Ubuntu) this works as required, however under BSD sed (as shipped in FreeBSD 10.1) it complains:

> sed: 1: "s/^USERNAME=('|"|)(.*)\ ...": RE error: empty (sub)expression

It seems to be the second pipe in `('|"|)` part of the pattern, removing it ( `('|")` ) clears the error, and I get the desired result on FreeBSD.  It also *appears* to give the correct results under Ubuntu, but since I’m trying to make code that is portable between the two systems, I want to better understand this part of the expression and why it doesn't work under BSD sed.

---

My understanding of the original pattern ( `('|"|)` ) is:

Match:

- a single quote (') — e.g. USERNAME='foo'
- a double quote (") — e.g. LOCALE="bar"
- nothing () — e.g. DELAY=10

**How can I port this pattern to BSD without breaking it for GNU sed?**

---

There’s another element that doesn’t work:

```
sed -rn "s/^$1=('|\"|)(.*)\1/\2/ip" "$CONF"
```

The `\1` is part of the pattern, and under GNU sed will insert whatever the outcome of `('|\"|)` is.  This doesn't work under BSD sed, is there a different, portable, notation?  Or would I have to repeat the first pattern verbatim?

---

EDIT: 
The contents of /etc/msm.conf might look something like this:

```
USERNAME='foo'
LOCALE="bar"
DELAY=10
SERVER_NAME="Ben's Server"
```

The expected output of `sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=('|\"|)(.*)\1/\2/ip" "/etc/msm.conf"` should be “`foo`”.

Comment: Can you provide an example string that it matches and its output when matched?

Comment: I would say to replace `('|\"|)` with `(['"]?)` but it seems to be the emptiness of the result that BSD `sed` is unliking, so that is unlikely to help.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing. It could be that BSD sed is complaining about an empty subexpression in `(foo|bar|)` and not that `\1` is empty. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: I did a little digging: `foo|` is not, in fact, valid in POSIX extented regexes, but GNU's implementation supports it. This leads me to believe that the empty subexpression in the `|` expression is the problem here, and that replacing it with `['\"]?` (`\"` only because it's inside a doubly-quoted shell string) should fix the issue.

Comment: @Wintermute `?` isn,t valid in POSIX is it ?

Comment: Not in basic syntax, but I think it's part of extended. Let me check that. EDIT: Yep, `?` is valid in extended.

Comment: @Wintermute Just checked it is valid in extended, my bad.

Comment: @TobySpeight & @Wintermute that works to get around the emptiness, thank you.  It still seems that `\1` inside the pattern isn’t working, making it difficult to have single quotes (as apostrophes) in the values within the config file—something the current script allows.

Comment: @forquare Does my solution not work ?

Comment: @User112638726 I’ve added a comment to your answer.  Short answer: almost.

Comment: `\1` inside the pattern not working - because you're using double quotes, sed sees just `1` there.  Escape the backslash, or use single quoting for that part (obviously the `"$1"` needs double quotes).

Comment: @TobySpeight That some wierd BSD thing, `\1` inside double quotes works for me.

Comment: @TobySpeight escaping the backslash doesn’t do it for me.     

(no `\1`): `sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=(['\"]?)(.*)/\2/pi" "/etc/msm.conf"` returns “ `foo'` ”.    

(escaped `\\1`): `sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=(['\"]?)(.*)\\1/\2/pi" "/etc/msm.conf"` returns “ `'` ”

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this `sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=(['\"]?)(.*)(['\"]?$)/\2/pi"`, but with `.*` being greedy it returns the end quote.  If I modify it to be `sed -rn "s/^USERNAME=(['\"]?)(.*)(['\"]$)/\2/pi"` then I don't get anything back if there are no surrounding quotes (e.g. in DELAY=10).  I’m thinking it might be time to look at another tool to see if there’s a different way to do it (without causing a dependancy on something like perl)

Comment: @forquare Sourcing the file isn't an option?

Comment: @hek2mgl I've been looking into that. It'd be my preferred method, but I think there will quite a lot of changes around the rest of the code to accommodate it (the current code sets a separate variable to say the main one is loaded, which just seems to be a tonne of extra work, but must have been done for some reason)

Comment: @forquare Can you use `awk` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl `awk` is certainly an option, as long as it's BSD friendly 

Answer (score 1):

This should work with the first capture group removed

```
sed "s/^USERNAME=\(['\"]\)\{0,1\}\([^'\"]*\)['\"]\{0,1\}/\2/p;d" "/etc/msm.conf"
```

Comment: This almost works, the output I get (if using the sample data in my OP edit) is `foo'`—see the trailing single quote.

Comment: @forquare Try new one

Comment: Alas, this doesn’t work for the `SERVER_NAME` case I added above. Although there shouldn’t be cases like this in the config file, it would be hard to rule out.  
The command, when run on `SERVER_NAME`, should return `Ben's Server`, however your edit returns `Bens Server"`.

Answer (score -2):

Your enclosing script has bad quoting.  Eliminate the outer double quotes like this:

```
    local from_conf=$(sed -rn "s/^$1=('|\"|)(.*)\1/\2/ip" "$CONF" | tail -n 1)
```

and you should be good to go.

As for the (...) issue, use `\(` and `\)`.  That's the portable notation.

Comment: The quotes outside `$()` are fine, if unnecessary. `\(` and `\)` are not portable notation but basic regex syntax. OP is using extended regex syntax (see the `-r` switch), in which `\(` means a literal `(` as opposed to a capture group.

Comment: The quotes outside $() must be removed.  It's what's causing his RE error because the first quote is matching against one of the unescaped quotes in the expression.

Comment: @DannyDaglas Quotes from outside the subshell are not seen inside it. There is nothing wrong with the quoting.

Comment: @DannyDaglas Shells that support `$()` understand that quotes inside that context do not match against quotes outside that context. There isn't a problem there. (If you have a shell which doesn't understand that your shell has problems.) Try it yourself and see: `v="$(echo bar"foo"baz)"; echo "$v"`